# Nant and ASP/.NET 1.1: do they get along?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, nant

I'm working on a mixed application (ASP, ASP.NET) and I brought up using Nant for deployments. The person I was talking to said that he'd heard that Nant wouldn't work for us because we have such a mixed bag (.NET 1.1 and .NET 2.0 apps, ASP, ASP.NET). I can't imagine that's the case, just seems really unlikely.

Your opinion? Have you built apps like this using Nant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NAnt's copy task lets you copy files from one location to another (which should do the majority of what you need for an ASP deployment?).

I've used it to push out ASP sites (e.g. grab latest from source, copy to drop location) as part of a larger build cycle that also was building ASP.NET 1.1.  Granted, that was on v0.85 a few years ago, but that's a production example of deploying a mixed bag at the same time.

If you *really* have to do something that isn't part of the built-in tasks or you can't find one in the [community](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/), there's nothing preventing you from writing your own task. If you can do it in the .NET framework, you can probably do it as part of a NAnt build.

So, short answer:  Yes, you can, but if you have anything more complicated than a basic build, you might have to write a custom task.

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you have several technologies in a single, deployments can become "interesting". Having worked on one myself we had our issues but got them ironed out. Unfortunately I never had the pleasure of working with nAnt myself but a former colleague of mine was raving about it.

He said they had some issues but they got them sorted out. I will send him to this question so he can post an answer, but it is definitely possible.